# How to specify which graphics adapter to use in CLI-only Ubuntu 16?

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, video

I have a customer with Ubuntu 16.04 in CLI - no GUI.  They have 2 video cards, both with video output ports.

How do I tell Ubuntu which card to use for primary video output?

The system boots and shows video during POST, but when it reaches Ubuntu the screen goes and stays black.

I can SSH in to the machine; nouveau is blacklisted, and only nvidia drivers are running:

```
root@ubuntu16:~# lsmod |grep -i nouv
root@ubuntu16:~# lsmod |grep -i nvi
nvidia_drm             45056  0
nvidia_modeset        765952  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              11476992  1 nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        147456  1 nvidia_drm
drm                   364544  3 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
root@ubuntu16:~# modinfo nvidia
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/video/nvidia.ko
alias:          char-major-195-*
version:        367.44
supported:      external
license:        NVIDIA
srcversion:     62594DC43B355E37A82EB4C
alias:          pci:v000010DEd00000E00sv*sd*bc04sc80i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc02i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc00i00*
depends:
vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           NVreg_Mobile:int
parm:           NVreg_ResmanDebugLevel:int
parm:           NVreg_RmLogonRC:int
parm:           NVreg_ModifyDeviceFiles:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileUID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileGID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileMode:int
parm:           NVreg_UpdateMemoryTypes:int
parm:           NVreg_InitializeSystemMemoryAllocations:int
parm:           NVreg_UsePageAttributeTable:int
parm:           NVreg_MapRegistersEarly:int
parm:           NVreg_RegisterForACPIEvents:int
parm:           NVreg_CheckPCIConfigSpace:int
parm:           NVreg_EnablePCIeGen3:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableMSI:int
parm:           NVreg_TCEBypassMode:int
parm:           NVreg_UseThreadedInterrupts:int
parm:           NVreg_MemoryPoolSize:int
parm:           NVreg_RegistryDwords:charp
parm:           NVreg_RmMsg:charp
parm:           NVreg_AssignGpus:charp
root@ubuntu16:~#
```

```
root@ubuntu16:/var/log# nvidia-smi
Wed Aug 24 16:50:52 2016
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.44                 Driver Version: 367.44                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 710      Off  | 0000:02:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 40%   29C    P0    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  2000MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:81:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   39C    P0    41W / 180W |      0MiB /  8113MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                  Not Supported                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
root@ubuntu16:/var/log#
```

This seems like it should be easy, but I can't find adequate documentation on it anywhere.  A little help please.

Comment: Post the output of `sudo xrandr -q`, and the contents of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Comment: Hey thlngan, thanks for your comment.  Xwindows is not installed on this system; it is CLI only.

Comment: Your system BIOS has decided that the monitor should be connected to your GTX 1080 rather than the GT 710. Check your BIOS settings.

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton thanks for your reply.  If you read my post, you'll notice that the BIOS selects the video adapter just fine when POSTing.  After handing control off to the OS (Ubuntu, in this case), it fails to show any kind of output.  Removing one of the video adapters resolves this issue, so it's a problem with priority.